# Using BSON on client with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, bson

For a financial system, I need to use a light-weight and fast protocol for transferring data from server to client with a Pushing Server (e.g. Socket.IO)

As you know, Packing and Unpacking with BSON also takes more time than using native JSON and maybe becomes a bottleneck itself.

I want to know, is this correct approach to use BSON instead of JSON for transferring data in order to reduce the size of messages?

Comment: If you use polling, you could take advantage of gzip compression and just use JSON. Is this out of the question?

Comment: @tjameson I have gzip compression also. It's maybe polling or pushing, it depends on client's browser. Exactly I'm looking for a better and faster protocol than native JSON.

Comment: What does the data look like? Also, gzip won't likely work with websockets because websockets expose a raw TCP stream.

Comment: Numeric data. For example: {"price": 12336.22, "count": 1000}

Answer (score 4):

> I want to know, is this correct approach to use BSON instead of JSON for
>   transferring data in order to reduce the size of messages?

It depends on the application. If it's a browser-based application, then the answer is **no**. Mainly because browser-based javascript does not (yet) have the ability to work with binary data. There are proposals like typed arrays that can sort-of do it if really necessary but even the specification for that is considered merely "draft" for now. Not to mention the fact that IE doesn't support it.

For browser based applications the standard method to reduce size of packets is to use compression like gzip. This can be configured on your server or it can be done in your web app.

For non-browser based app the answer is **it depends**. Projects like MongoDB has had great success with BSON. On the other hand the web as a whole have been running well with just JSON+compression. The best answer is for you to benchmark it yourself and see if it makes sense in your case.

Comment: Well, typed arrays [*are* supported](http://caniuse.com/typedarrays) in all modern browsers, IE10 included. Not supported in IE <= 9 though.